# Word2Vec load error: No such file or directory: '...word2vec_withString10-100-200.model.wv.vectors.npy

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, word2vec

When I load the Word2Vec model, I have a problem that I cannot solve.

The code to run is as follows:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
w2v_model = Word2Vec.load('E:/projectlzy/data/word2vec_withString10-100-200.model')
```

The error is as follows:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 from gensim.models import Word2Vec
----> 2 w2v_model = Word2Vec.load('E:/projectlzy/data/word2vec_withString10-100-200.model')

File D:\Anaconda\envs\mykeras\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py:1141, in Word2Vec.load(cls, *args, **kwargs)
   1122 """Load a previously saved :class:`~gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec` model.
   1123 
   1124 See Also
   (...)
   1138 
   1139 """
   1140 try:
-> 1141     model = super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
   1143     # for backward compatibility for `max_final_vocab` feature
   1144     if not hasattr(model, 'max_final_vocab'):

File D:\Anaconda\envs\mykeras\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py:1230, in BaseWordEmbeddingsModel.load(cls, *args, **kwargs)
   1199 @classmethod
   1200 def load(cls, *args, **kwargs):
   1201     """Load a previously saved object (using :meth:`~gensim.models.base_any2vec.BaseWordEmbeddingsModel.save`) from file.
   1202 
   1203     Also initializes extra instance attributes in case the loaded model does not include them.
   (...)
   1228 
   1229     """
-> 1230     model = super(BaseWordEmbeddingsModel, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
   1231     if not hasattr(model, 'ns_exponent'):
   1232         model.ns_exponent = 0.75

File D:\Anaconda\envs\mykeras\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py:602, in BaseAny2VecModel.load(cls, fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
    575 @classmethod
    576 def load(cls, fname_or_handle, **kwargs):
    577     """Load a previously saved object (using :meth:`gensim.models.base_any2vec.BaseAny2VecModel.save`) from a file.
    578 
    579     Parameters
   (...)
    600 
    601     """
--> 602     return super(BaseAny2VecModel, cls).load(fname_or_handle, **kwargs)

File D:\Anaconda\envs\mykeras\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py:436, in SaveLoad.load(cls, fname, mmap)
    433 compress, subname = SaveLoad._adapt_by_suffix(fname)
    435 obj = unpickle(fname)
--> 436 obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)
    437 logger.info("loaded %s", fname)
    438 return obj

File D:\Anaconda\envs\mykeras\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py:467, in SaveLoad._load_specials(self, fname, mmap, compress, subname)
    465     logger.info("loading %s recursively from %s.* with mmap=%s", attrib, cfname, mmap)
    466     with ignore_deprecation_warning():
--> 467         getattr(self, attrib)._load_specials(cfname, mmap, compress, subname)
    469 for attrib in getattr(self, '__numpys', []):
    470     logger.info("loading %s from %s with mmap=%s", attrib, subname(fname, attrib), mmap)

File D:\Anaconda\envs\mykeras\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py:478, in SaveLoad._load_specials(self, fname, mmap, compress, subname)
    476     val = np.load(subname(fname, attrib))['val']
    477 else:
--> 478     val = np.load(subname(fname, attrib), mmap_mode=mmap)
    480 with ignore_deprecation_warning():
    481     setattr(self, attrib, val)

File D:\Anaconda\envs\mykeras\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py:390, in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
    388     own_fid = False
    389 else:
--> 390     fid = stack.enter_context(open(os_fspath(file), "rb"))
    391     own_fid = True
    393 # Code to distinguish from NumPy binary files and pickles.

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:/projectlzy/data/word2vec_withString10-100-200.model.wv.vectors.npy'
```

Is the .npy file generated when the .model file is generated? Is it necessary to load the word2vec.model file with the corresponding .npy file? Or am I using the wrong version of gensim? I used gensim==3.8.3.

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do **not** post screenshots of code or error messages, see how to create a [mre].

Comment: Thank you, I will pay attention to this issue next time

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `.save()` method of a Gensim model class to save a large model, it is common for *multiple* files to be created, for efficiency when reloading.

These will typically include both the main filename you specified – here `word2vec_withString10-100-200.model.wv.vectors.npy` – and one or more additional files that use that name with extra suffixes.

In order to reload the model, all those files must be kept together. (If you move the main file, you need to move the side files to stay alongside it in any destination directory.) If you don't retain/move all the files together, you could get an error like the one you're hitting.